# "Please insert proper boot device"

Tags: boot, system-installation

After I install Linux with no problems and load into the OS again with no problems the first time I restart the computer it will no longer load up Linux again. Instead it asks me to insert a proper boot device or insert boot media into the drive. I was wondering if anybody could help me with this.

Comment: It would be the problem with `grub`(the boot-loader). You can give a try to [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). You'll need Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB.

Comment: I downloaded Boot-repair and made an ISO image of the program on a disk but after re-installing Linux then trying to use this disk at start up I still get the same “Please insert proper boot device”

Comment: No, no, You don't have to re-install Ubuntu. Also you don't have to make boot-repair bootable CD. I though you would be able to get all from the link. You've to boot Ubuntu using Live(bootable) CD/DVD/USB and then you've to chose **Try Ubuntu** (not Install Ubuntu) option. When Ubuntu starts you've to install [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) as described in the link. Also this type of message comes when you changes some settings from **BIOS**. Are you sure in **BIOS** the HDD is set to be in first under **Boot Device Priority**?

Comment: Also make sure your removable drives are empty of media (in case you have the BIOS set to boot CD or FDD first)